# How can I remove darkness from behind objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, transparency

I am getting problem like below image. First trees row getting darkness of behind second trees row. you can understand clearly using below image.

I am using z-transparency to hide my plan background.

How can remove darkness of behind row from front row trees.? any one can help me.?

[image]

** Edited **

[image]

This is working for me. It give output like above image.

Answer (score 3):

Your image alpha channel must be used for the mix factor between the transparent area and the color information (diffuse). So, just connect the *Alpha* output of the image node to the factor input of your *Mix Shader* node. This makes it so that only the parts of the image that are transparent are actually appear as transparent.

Just a proposal. Unfortunately we don't know you node tree for your tree planes.

[image: Node tree example.]

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer, or it might get flagged/deleted.

Comment: Sorry, but I have saved my post to early and have seen the info about the post length later.

Comment: hey @ChristophWerner i have try your node connection but not working for me.

Comment: May I see your tree image in blender please? Maybe it has no alpha? actually it should work like described. What do you see as result after using my proposal?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by a **translucent shader.**

What that shader does, is when light is coming from **behind** an object, the object gets lit. This could cause that effect, because the other trees are blocking the light coming from the back.

Perhaps you accidentally used a translucent shader instead of a transparent shader?

Please share node setup if you would like a clear answer, as it is hard to answer with this information.

Also check out Andrew's shader encyclopedia for info on those shaders, and more. http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia/

Comment: No man i used transparent shader, see above node connection image.I share it.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure. If you upload the .blend file it might help, but maybe not. Are you using Internal or Cycles? Where is your light? Are you just using world lighting?

Comment: I am working with cycles and i am using world light.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with yours... I honestly don't know why anything is showing up at all with your node setup. The transparent should be going into the top of the mix, and the diffuse into the bottom. If you change them that may fix it. There is just something weird going on. I have a feeling it has to do with the alpha mask for your trees being only partial, and partly off. I duplicated your scene (with mix flipped) and it works fine for me. If you want more help, you really need to upload the blend file.

Comment: Oh wait!!! I know what's wrong. I'll add another answer with the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem with your node setup.

- First, **flip** the inputs to the *mix shader*.
- Next, **plug** the color from the texture into the *diffuse* shader.
- Finally, **change** the color of the *transparent* shader to **pure white.**

Answer (score 0):

Increase the bounces for transparency in the light paths section: [image]