# Cycles: Front plane's alpha pixels getting 'canceled' by rear plane's alpha pixels

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I am rendering a scene with three planes that all have emission shaders.  Farthest from the camera is the room plane (#1) with a movie texture, close to the camera is the face plane (#2) that has an RGBA movie (alpha channel) texture, and flying across the scene is a plate plane (#3) that has a PNG image texture (alpha channel).  *Lighting is irrelevant, since there are no other objects in the scene.* The #3 alpha is working as it enters the scene (the green circle below), but as it moves in front of plane #2, #2's alpha bits are turning #3s alpha bits to black (the red circle below). [image: Rendered view of scene]
Here you can see the object view with the two planes overlapping (the plate plane is rotated about 45 degrees) When #3 completely overlaps #2, the plate is surrounded completely by a black square. [image]
The transparency is accomplished with the "standard" set of nodes on both planes #2 & #3. [image]

Comment: Try increasing bounces for transparency.https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45272/how-can-i-remove-darkness-from-behind-objects/45361#45361

Comment: I see that in your second screen shot, in the Render Context Tab, under the Film panel, "Transparent" has not been enabled. Have you tried enabling it?

Comment: YES! Cegaton you nailed it.  The Light Paths transparency (both Min & Max)  were set to zero as I erroneously thought that since there were no lights in the scene, that wasn't needed. I failed to understand that the setting also related to the EMITTED light from the emitter shaders.  One bounce is all it took!  Cegaton, please post the answer & take the credit.