# Glass Problem with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I'm new here. I'm making glass tube and I encountered this problem(see below the red circles). Any suggestion to solve the problem? I provide the nodes setup I created...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try this:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles and increase transparency bounces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45272/how-can-i-remove-darkness-from-behind-objects/45361#45361

Comment: @cegaton, yup increasing the transparency bounces works. Thank you every much!

Comment: While waiting for the replies solution.. also I read this one:
https://www.3dtotal.com/tutorial/1737-how-to-engrave-glass-in-blender-part-2-blender-by-filippo-veniero-object-drink-model?page=2